# Codeigniter sending contact form message

Tags: codeigniter, email

I am working on sending email. I am on windows 7.

Here is my controller:

```
public function ilet(){
        $name    = $this->input->post("name");
        $email   = $this->input->post("email");
        $message = $this->input->post("message");

        $config = array(
            "protocol"    => "smtp",
            "smtp_host"   => "mail.pratikesnaf.com",
            "smtp_port"   =>"587",
            "smtp_user"   =>"deste@pratikesnaf.com",
            "smtp_password"   =>"********",
            "starttls"    =>true,
            "charset"     =>"utf-8",
            "mailtype"    =>"html",
            "wordwrap"    => true,
            "newline"     =>"\r\n",
        );

        $this->load->library("email", $config);

         $this->email->from("mail.pratikesnaf.com");
         $this->email->to("mail.pratikesnaf.com");           
         $this->email->subject("Müşteri bilgi mesajı");
         $this->email->message("Kişinin Adı - " . $name .
          " - Kişinin Email Adresi - " . $email . " - Kişinin Mesajı - " . $message);


         $send = $this->email->send();

         if($send)
         {
             echo "Mail gönderme işlemi başarılı";
         }
         else {
             echo "Başarısız";
             echo $this->email->print_debugger();
         }


    }
```

after that i fulfill the inputs and i submit the button. it says an error like this:

Başarısız220 server.tescilmerkezi.net ESMTP Exim 4.76 Tue, 10 Jul 2018 18:00:47 +0300 
hello: 250-server.tescilmerkezi.net Hello www.pratikesnaf.com [185.85.237.26]
250-SIZE 20971520
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP

Can you please help me how can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

try to change these lines:

```
$this->email->from("mail.pratikesnaf.com");
$this->email->to("mail.pratikesnaf.com");
```

to

```
$this->email->from("yoursenderemail@pratikesnaf.com");
$this->email->to("receiveremail@blabla.com");
```

Comment: Unfortunately sir.